# Return default xml namespace

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I am trying to retrieve what the current 'default xml namespace' is.

In multiple places, within some code I am digging through, there is the current syntax.

```
default xml namespace = new Namespace(.....);
```

for debugging purposes I would like to do something like the following.

```
var ns:Namespace = default xml namespace;
```

but obviously this does not work, I am trying to find the syntax that can do this.

Comment: the namespace is just a string, keep a reference of it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will helps.

Try to store the default namespace in a static variable.

```
private static var _defaultNS:Namaspace;
...
public static function set defaultNS(ns:Namespace)
{
    _defaultNS = ns;
    default xml namespace = ns;
}

public static function get defaultNS():Namespace
{
    return _defaultNS;
}
```

Comment: It's not me setting the default namespace, it's someone else's code. I am just trying to wade through it all.

Comment: Hmm, something strange is happening here. I think this approach cannot work due to the fact it is now in a new block scope.. so once the set function finishes, the namespace is no longer set.